# JavaFX: Combobox bidirectional exclusion

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am currently trying to implement some sort of "bidirectional exclusion" behaviour between two comboboxes, however am failing when the user selects a value in both comboboxes.

The basic idea is that if you select an item in combobox A, it will no longer be available for selection in combobox B, and vice versa.

My current code is as follows (outer class omitted for simplicity):

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{
    final var sourceList = baseList.filtered(new ExclusionPredicate(null));
    final var targetList = baseList.filtered(new ExclusionPredicate(null));

    initChangeListener(sourceSelection, targetList);
    initChangeListener(targetSelection, sourceList);

    sourceSelection.setItems(sourceList);
    targetSelection.setItems(targetList);
}

private void initChangeListener(ComboBox<Item> comboBox, FilteredList<Item> targetList)
{
    comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue != null)
        {
            targetList.setPredicate(((ExclusionPredicate) targetList.getPredicate()).updateExclusion(newValue));
        }
    }));
}

private class ExclusionPredicate implements Predicate<Item>
{
    private final Item excluded;

    private ExclusionPredicate(Mailbox excluded)
    {
        this.excluded = excluded;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Item item)
    {
        if(item == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return item.equals(excluded);
    }

    private ExclusionPredicate updateExclusion(Item excluded)
    {
        return new ExclusionPredicate(excluded);
    }
}
```

When only one combobox contains a value, everything is fine - you can no longer see the selected value in combobox 2.
As soon as I select a value in combobox 2, however, **BOTH** comboboxes lose their value.

Am I doing something horribly wrong, or is it not possible to implement such a behaviour in JavaFX? Tried searching here / in Google, could only find answers regarding dependent comboboxes, not bidirectionally linked ones.

Comment: Returning `true` on a predicate means to show it. It seems that your predicates are returning `false` when you pass it an `Item` to test against. Also, your `valueProperty` looks a little suspect to me. I would expect you to just say `targetList.setPredicate(new ExclusionPredicate(newValue));` after the `null` check, instead of getting the current one and returning a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, even changing the convoluted updateExclusion to a simple new call and fixing the predicate test (adding a negation), the behaviour is still the same. As soon as I select a value in the opposite combobox, the other one gets cleared immediately (filtering works properly tho).